# Django: Use ajax to add an HTML element

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I've researched this topic for quite some time, but I just can't seem to find the answer or explanation I'm looking for. I have a Django app with a discussion board (similar to Facebook's timeline), and I want to know how to use ajax to make a new post or comment on someone's post.

Here is the template code:

```
<form action='/create_post/' method="post" id="post-form">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {% render_field post_form.body id="post-text" class+="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Say howdy to your neighbors!" %}
      <div id="comment-row" class="row">
        <button id="post-submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the "create_post" view:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.POST:
       # get POST data
       body = request.POST['body']
       author = request.user
       apartment_id = author.tenant.apartment.id

       # create new Post
       post = Post(body=body, author=author, apartment_id=apartment_id)
       post.save()

       return HttpResponseRedirect('/stream/')
   else:
       return HttpResponse('<p>here</p>')
```

and the `return HttpResponseRedirect('/stream/`) calls:

```
def stream(request):
   # get data to pass to template
   user = request.user
   post_form = PostForm()
   comment_form = CommentForm()
   apartment_id = user.tenant.apartment.id
   posts = Post.objects.filter(apartment_id=apartment_id).order_by('-id')
   comments = Comment.objects.all().order_by('id')

   return render(request, 'stream/stream.html', {
       'user': user,
       'post_form': post_form,
       'comment_form': comment_form,
       'posts': posts,
       'comments': comments,
   })
```

where this renders a template that renders each post with each comment.

Is there some sort of way to simply re-render the '/stream/' template (which would include the new post) without refreshing the page? That seems like the cleanest way to do it to me. Does the django-ajax package do this? Because if so, I could not get it to work. If not, what is the cleanest/'right' way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I think is the best solution, and that is to call the view in jQuery via the ajax() method.

The script:

```
    function create_post() {
      console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
      $.ajax({
          url : "/create_post/", // the endpoint
          type : "POST", // http method
          data : { body : $('#post-text').val() }, // data sent with the post request

          // handle a successful response
          success : function(json) {
              $('#posts').load(' #posts', function(){$(this).find('#posts').unwrap()});
          },

          // handle a non-successful response
          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
              $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                  " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
              console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
          }
      });
    };

    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
      create_post();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago, I wrote an example using AngularJS, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/Gocht/31cc901dbb6fcffa7913). Please make me know if it works.

Comment: Could you explain what each file does/what the process here is? Where does 'loaded.html' come in to play? Also what does the .config function in the angular module do? What is $interpolateProvider?

Comment: @rigdonmr Angulas uses `{{ }}` syntax to render variables, Django uses the same syntax, that's why I used `.confg` function and the `$interpolateProvider` to replace that syntax to avoid confusing. But since you're working with JQuery, you don't need it.